Elisp in properties header args
I use this:
#+property: header-args:R :session (concat "*R:" (f-base (buffer-file-name)) "*")

Is it possible to evaluate Elisp code by putting it inside back ticks or something like that? Maybe something like:
#+property: header-args:R :session *R`(f-base (buffer-file-name))`*


Not possible: the value is an uninterpreted string. See OrgSyntax.
